# is a interface that is implemented considered a superclass of the implementation?

Tags: java

HashSet implements interface Set extends interface Collection which extends interface iterable
Can we then say that HashSet is said to implement the interface Iterable?
What does this look like in terms of the JVM runtime and classloading? In there just one big class created called HashSet (which includes all Iterable methods)?

Comment: An interface is not a class, so it would be wrong to call it a superclass. A supertype is a more accurate term as an interface defines a type, but not a class.

Comment: See the documentation about HotSpot (the OpenJDK JIT) implementation of [virtual calls](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/VirtualCalls) and [interface calls](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/InterfaceCalls).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If class A implements interface X and interface X extends interface Y, then A implements interface Y as well. That is how extending interfaces works.
It is still just one class, even if it implements a load of different interfaces.

An interface is just a specification: it declares that some class provides a certain set of methods. When an interface extends another interface, it incorporates all those methods and whichever extra ones it adds. Thus any class implementing that interface must provide all the methods specified by all the interfaces and their super-interfaces.

So yes, HashSet implements the Iterable interface.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html